# DOMNode->ChildNodes->length returns incorrect value

Tags: php, web-scraping, domdocument, domxpath

I have a PHP script that parses a webpage and navigates through it using DOMDocument and DOMXpath libraries. Wen running `$tr->ChildNodes->length` to get the 3 `<td>`, the instruction returns 6, where 0 returns the first `<td>`, 1 is a blank string(19), 2 is the second `<td>`, 3 is again the blank string(19), 4 is the third `<td>`, 5 is another time the empty string(19) and 6 is the entire HTML of the page. (tested using `$dom->saveHTML($tr->childNodes->item(0)` etc.)
How do i make `->length` return the correct number? Why does it behave so strange?

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <span>...</span>
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="..."><img ...></a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>
    <span>
      <a href="...">...</a>
      <br>
      <ahref="...">...</a>
    </span>
    <span>...</span>
    <br><br>
    <a href="...">...</a>, <a href="...">...</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="...">...</a> | <a href="...">...</a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Please note that i omitted some attributes like style, class, data, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is not quite "strange". In DOM, line breaks are actually treated as empty nodes. To get the "correct" number of children, you have to either remove line breaks from the document you are trying to parse beforehand, or get all the children and remove the empty elements from this node list.

Comment: Thanks for the informations. But doesn't `$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false` help in removing unwanted whitespace?

Comment: I suppose it's useless in your case. It helps to preserve indentation of the elements in the code, and here you deal not with white spaces but with new line characters. So you better just iterate over the node list and `$tr->removeChild()` the empty elements